# How do I answer Chapter 18, Exercise 5, Haskell From First Principles not in terms of "flipType" from Exercise 6

Tags: haskell

The exercise is to define the function `meh`, which I did as follows:

```
meh :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
meh input_list transform = concatMonads transformed_input
  where 
    transformed_input = fmap transform input_list

concatMonads :: Monad m => [m b] -> m [b]
concatMonads [] = pure []
concatMonads (first:rest) = (concatMonads rest) >>= (appendListToMonadContent first)

appendListToMonadContent :: Monad m => m b -> [b] -> m [b]
appendListToMonadContent cur to_append = fmap (\first -> first:to_append) cur
```

The next exercise is to define `flipType :: Monad m => [m b] -> m [b]` and the hint is "reuse `meh`" (which is easy: `flipType l = meh l id`). However, my answer to question 5 uses `flipType`, it is just called `concatMonads`, so it is obvious that I did it differently than the authors were intending.

How can I define `meh` without using `flipType`?

Comment: One way is http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.Traversable.html#line-237 If you have any question about this implementation fell free to ask.

Comment: Not completely relevant, but your `concatMonads` sequences the monadic effects right-to-left, which is unusual. E.g. `concatMonads [print 1>>pure 1 , print 2>>pure 2]` returns the list `[1,2]` but prints 2 and 1 in that order, AFAICS. The answer by Chris below would print 1 and 2 instead.

Comment: @chi Good point. That book does not teach monads in terms of side-effects - so I wasn't thinking about them. The monad laws it gives are r & l identity and associativity, they don't include sequencing. They probably should since people expect it.

Comment: Technically, sequencing is not an equational law, but rather the _absence_ of a commutative law which lets us reorder the effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
meh :: Monad m => [a] -> (a -> m b) -> m [b]
```

The first argument can be `[]`, and that's easy.

```
meh [] _ = pure []
```

The main case should perform the action provided by f, then recursively `meh` the rest of the list, and collect the results:

```
meh (x:xs) f = do
    r <- f x
    rs <- meh xs f
    pure (r:rs)
```

or without `do` notation:

```
meh (x:xs) f =
    f x >>= \r -> meh xs f >>= \rs -> pure (r:rs)
```

or in `Applicative` terms:

```
meh (x:xs) f = (:) <$> f x <*> meh xs f
```